# how many devices can i use for development using company account

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

If I have **company developer account**, how many windows phone devices can I use for windows phone development?

I've read somewhere, that you can only use three unlocked devices per account. But how about a company, which has for example 50 developers working on several different apps?

Comment: 3. But you can send a support ticket to Microsoft asking to increase that limit. They also may increase the limit of apps that can be sideloaded to a phone, that is 10 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loged on the developper center ([dev.windowsphone.com](http://dev.windowsphone.com)) you click on "dashboard" (on the top) > "account" (on the left) > "phones".

I've a company account and this sentence appear :

```
Maximum number of phones you can register: 3
```

You can use Windows phone emulators for all developer, and test your application with just three Windows-phone...

Answer (score 1):

Ask Microsoft support to increase your limit and describe your use case. It helped in our case.